# How to work with M2M relationship in django-rest

Tags: django-rest-framework

Let's start from the models used in the django docs about the M2M relationship that uses the through argument to point to the model that will act as an intermediary.

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, 
                                     through='Membership')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_joined']
```

Assume now I want to have a rest **read-write** view for the Group model which contains also all the Person inside each group, **ordered by date_joined field**. The json serialization I would like to obtain is the following (the members are described only with their id):

```py
{
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "U2", 
    "members": [
       20, 
       269, 
       134, 
       12,
    ]
}
```

I wrote a serializer:

```py
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = serializers.SlugRelatedField(source='membership_set', 
                                           many=True, 
                                           read_only=False,
                                           slug_field='person_id', 
                                           required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'members')
```

While for read operations it works well, it doesn't for writing. How should I define the serializer so that, given the above defined serialization, it will proceed by:

1. Create the Group object
2. Add each members to the Group (by creating a Membership object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#manytomanyfields-with-a-through-model) you can see that what you are trying to do works only for read operations. This is a common problem for DRF, as stated by its creator, Tom  Christie, in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-rest-framework/vCl2I_EzJnE/qwRdIdxiUe4J) comment.

Also, for the JSON serialization that you want, it is recommended to use a PK related field, as shown [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#primarykeyrelatedfield), though that won't help with creation of the Group object and adding of members. You will have to write that code yourself.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

Code snippet for adding each person to the Group by creating Memberships:

```
def post_save(self, obj, created=False):
    # obj represents the Group object
    if created:
        # Test to see if the Group was successfully created
        members = self.request.DATA.get('members', None)
        if members not None:
            for id in members:
                person = Person.objects.get(id=id)
                membership, m_created = Membership.objects.get_or_create(person=person, group=obj)
                # Here you can use m_created to see if the membership already existed and to do whatever else you need.
```

This implementation assumes that you have declared your date_joined with *auto_now*. If not, you should also pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer you gave me with also the link to the relevant part of the documentation or the answer of the author on the point. It's a pity what I was trying to do is not very much supported by the framework. Could you please suggest me a way to accomplish the task by writing the code on my own ? What's the right way ? Thank you again!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) As for the creation part, you can do it in two places: in the **post/create** method or in the **post_save** method. I suggest it to be done in the **post_save** because that means you are allowing the framework to create the Group object and all that is left to do is add the members. I will edit my answer with a small code snippet for how to use this method.

Comment: Thank you so much, your support is very appreciated!