# Saving django model with many to many relationship to database in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to be able to do a post on an api endpoint to save an adgroup model.The model has a many to many field. I know I need to overwrite the create() method.But How is where I am stuck at . The incoming request data will have the id for the other model (creative). This id will already be present in the creative table.

Django creates another table called adgroup_creative to hold this M2M relationship.I need to populate that table when saving this adgroup object.

```
class AdGroup(models.Model):
    adgroup_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Name")
    creative = models.ManyToManyField(Creative, verbose_name="Creative")

class Creative(models.Model):
    creative_name= models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Name", default=0)
    ad_type= models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=1,verbose_name="Ad Type")

class AdGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AdGroup
        fields = ('id','adgroup_name','creative')

class CreativeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Creative
        fields = ('id','creative_name')

class AdGroupViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = AdGroup.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = AdGroupSerializer
```

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46160/django-rest-framework-add-remove-to-a-list

[Save a many-to-many model in Django/REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598940/save-a-many-to-many-model-in-django-rest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at the [serializer relation documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/).

You don't need anything special if you simply use ID to represent a M2M relation with DRF. You'll need to override the `create`/`update` methods only if you intend to provide non existing related objects or use nested serializers.

In the current case, you don't need nested serializers because you want to provide related instances' IDs.