# POST requests error for Django many-to-many models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm receiving the following error when trying to make a POST request to create a particular model within the sqlite3 database:

```
"<Article>" needs to have a value for field "article" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

I'm building a REST API using the Django REST Framework and I have two models with a many-to-many relationship as follows:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
```

The corresponding extract in views.py for an Article is as follows:

```
class ArticleList(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I'm assuming the issue is that the article doesn't get saved before the POST request is finished as I'm able to perform all CRUD operations fine using Django's database API.

The PublicationSerializer is as follows:

```
class PublicationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=120, allow_blank=False)


def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
    instance.save()
    return instance

def create(self, validated_data):
    return Publication.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

The ArticleSerializer is as follows:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    headline = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=120, allow_blank=False)
    publications = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.headline = validated_data.get('headline', instance.headline)
    instance.publications = validated_data.get('publications', instance.publications)
    instance.save()
    return instance

def create(self, validated_data):
    return Article.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

A sample of the data I attempted to post:

```
{
"headline": "Trending Topics",
"publications": []
}
```

What's the best approach to solving this issue?

Comment: Why is the view named `ArticleList` and the serializer it uses `PublicationSerializer`? Could you update the question with the `PublicationSerializer` code (fields, model etc) and a sample of the data you attempt to post?

Comment: Apologies, this was a mistake. I've updated the question with more information

Comment: From the error, you striped too much of your models before pasting there. It complains about an "article" field from the "Article" Model while the model posted here doesn't have any.

Comment: @Linovia those are the complete models. A similar issue was raised in this question however it didn't receive a conclusive answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598940/save-a-many-to-many-model-in-django-rest

Comment: Does it end with a backtrace ? If so it'll help a lot to have it.